# Returning other related nodes when one of the Nodes is known

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have data in the form

```
(n:Node)-[HAS_ADDRESS]->(r:Address{name:'Goa'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_ADDRESS]->(r:Address{name:'India'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_ANCHOR]->(k:Keyword{name:'accounting'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_ANCHOR]->(k:Keyword{name:'Keyword 2'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_ANCHOR]->(k:Keyword{name:'Keyword 3'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_PHOTO]->(ph:Photo{name:'photo1'}),
(n:Node)-[HAS_PHOTO]->(ph:Photo{name:'photo2'}),
etc...
```

nodes are stored in the following format

```
(n:Node{name:'',rating:'',international_phone_number:''})
(ph:Photo{id:''})
(k:Keyword{name:''})
```

I have the value of 'k' and 'n' so i used

```
MATCH (k:Keyword { name: 'accounting'})<-[:HAS_ANCHOR]-(p)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(l:Address‌​),(p)-[:HAS_PHOTO]->‌​(ph)
WHERE ph.crawl=1 AND l.name = 'Goa' 
WITH p, l
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(other_r:Address)
return p.name as name, p.rating as rating, p.formatted_address as address,p.international_phone_number as international_phone_number,collect(ph.photo_reference) as photos, l as locations, other_r as other_addresses
ORDER BY p.rating DESC
```

I am clueless on how to get the node with all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only know about **"Node 1"**, you need to take **"n"** from the first match and use it to get the other peers of **"r"**.

```
// your original query that matches n and r based on the known node r
MATCH (n:Node)->[k:HAS_ANCHOR]->(r:Node) 
WHERE r.name = 'Node 1'

// use the result of n from the first query to find peers of r 
WITH n, r
MATCH (n)-[:HAS_ANCHOR]->(other_r:Node) 
RETURN n, r, other_r
```

**UPDATE** 
Based on comments, does this work?

```
// match the anchor based on the keyword
MATCH (k:Keyword { name: 'accounting'})<-[:HAS_ANCHOR]-(p)
WHERE (p)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(:Address‌​ {name: 'Goa'})

// optionally match and collect the photos
WITH p
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:HAS_PHOTO]->‌​(ph)
WHERE ph.crawl=1  

//match and collect all of the addresses 
WITH p, l, collect(ph.photo_reference) as photos
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_ADDRESS]->(r:Address)
RETURN p.name as name, 
   p.rating as rating, 
   p.formatted_address as address,
   p.international_phone_number as international_phone_number,
   photos,
   collect(r) as addresses 
ORDER BY p.rating DESC
```